# KSS - Generating a styleguide with KSS-Node and Grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, kss

It does not seem to create the relevant directories, as well as generate the styleguide.

I have attached relevant imagery, can anyone see a mistake?

It runs the task in Grunt with no errors, but nothing is generated or outputted

[image: Directory Structure]

[image: Grunt Shell Task]

[image: Grunt Task Register]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [stdout](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell#stdout) option for the grunt-shell task to see a possible error output of kss-node.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [grunt-styleguide](https://github.com/indieisaconcept/grunt-styleguide) which works fine with both StyleDocco and KSS.

Here's my configuration with the default yeoman webapp generator :

```
styleguide: {
  options: {
    template: {
      src: 'app/styleguide-template'
    },
    framework: {
      name: 'kss'
    }
  },
  all: {
    files: [{
      '.tmp/styleguide': 'app/styles/main.scss'
    }]
  }
},
```